# gwt CellTree change open/close item image dynamic

Tags: image, gwt, dynamic

Hi I have a CellTree which has selectable RootItems.

I want to change the open-/close item image of a selected RootItem

is it possible to change the image dynamic?

Im using GWT 2.5 thx :)

Answer (score 3):

This is too late, but I hope it will help other googlers.
First, define an interface:

```
public interface TreeResources extends CellTree.Resources {

@ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
@Source("cellTreeClosedArrow.gif")
ImageResource cellTreeClosedItem();

 /**
 * An image indicating an open branch.
 */
@ImageOptions(flipRtl = true)
@Source("cellTreeOpenArrow.gif")
ImageResource cellTreeOpenItem();
}
```

Where cellTreeClosedArrow.gif and cellTreeOpenArrow.gif are the names (paths) to your custom images. 
Next thing is to instantiate the above interface (in you view):

```
CellTree.Resources treeResource = GWT.create(TreeResources.class);
```

Last thing to do is associating the treeResource to your tree:
Example:

```
tree = new CellTree(myTreeViewModel , null,treeResource);
```

I hope this is what you need.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In what folder should the new image files be put?